# Loss of data warning when copying to a data structure of smaller type

Tags: c++

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and I have code such as the following:

```
void f()
{
    std::vector<short> vecshort(10);
    std::vector<long> veclong(10);
    std::copy(veclong.begin(), veclong.end(), vecshort.begin());
}
```

This gives warning:

```
warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'long' to 'short', possible loss of data
```

The trouble is the real code is in some templates. The user can instantiate the templates such that this warning occurs, but the logic of the code prevents any actual loss of data. How can I suppress this warning in a nice way? If it weren't in `std::copy` I could put a cast.

Edit: The code will be used in other compilers and it would be frowned upon for me to use pragmas.

Comment: `std::stansform` with a unary operator that does the cast/conversion?

Comment: you can always disable it : #pragma warning(disable:4244)

Comment: See here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a013dd94-8aa9-4991-803a-fd38c6af8658/how-to-get-rid-of-the-warning-c4244-and-c4101

Comment: Warning aside, why use `std::copy`? Why not use the constructor itself as `std::vector<short> vecshort(veclong.begin(), veclong.end());`? Or `insert()` function, in case the vector already exists?

Comment: @Nawaz This is just an example. The real code uses iterators from unseen data structures.

Comment: @NeilKirk: But that doesn't make `std::copy` a better option. If you can use `std::copy`, you could use constructor or insert function.

Comment: @Nawaz How? My real function as iterator parameters, not the data structure.

Comment: @NeilKirk: If you meant the destination is iterator, not a container, then OK. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your best bet is to use `std::transform` with a predicate (or lambda) that does the cast for you (since you're asserting no loss of data converting to the smaller type).

```
template <typename To>
struct convert_to
{
    template<typename From>
    To operator()(From source) const { return static_cast<To>(source); }
};

std::transform(veclong.begin(), veclong.end(), vecshort.begin(), convert_to<short>());
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `std::copy`, you can use `std::transform`:

```
short to_short(long i)
{
    return static_cast<short>(i);
}

std::vector<short> vShort;
std::vector<long> vLong(10);
std::transform(vLong.begin(), vLong.end(), std::back_inserter<std::vector<short>>(vShort), to_short);
```

You could also do the cast in a lambda.

Comment: This is a good idea. I will make the types of the cast function template parameters for my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can put #pragma to suppress the specific warning.

```
> #pragma warning(push)
> #pragma warning(disable: 4244) // possible loss of data
> #include <algorithm> 
> #pragma warning(pop)
```

This is of course compiler specific.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I don't want to disable the warning in general. It might show up other issues.

Comment: Mark B.'s solution looks better anyway.